# Running a Dash app within a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have an existing Flask app, and I want to have a route to *another app*. More concretely, the second app is a [Plotly Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) app. How can I run my Dash app within my existing Flask app?

```
@app.route('/plotly_dashboard') 
def render_dashboard():
    # go to dash app
```

I also tried adding a route to the Dash instance, since it's a Flask app, but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Answer (score 80):

From the [docs](https://plot.ly/dash/deployment):

> The underlying Flask app is available at `app.server`.
>
> ```
> import dash
> app = dash.Dash(__name__)
> server = app.server
> ```
>
> You can also pass your own Flask app instance into Dash:
>
> ```
> import flask
> server = flask.Flask(__name__)
> app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)
> ```

Now that you have the Flask instance, you can add whatever routes and other functionality you need.

```
@server.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

---

To the more general question "how can I serve two Flask instances next to each other", assuming you don't end up using one instance as in the above Dash answer, you would use [`DispatcherMiddleware`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/middleware/dispatcher/) to mount both applications.

```
dash_app = Dash(__name__)
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

application = DispatcherMiddleware(flask_app, {'/dash': dash_app.server})
```

Answer (score 39):

Set `url_base_pathname` in your Dash instance.

```
app_flask = flask.Flask(__name__)

app_dash = dash.Dash(__name__, server=app_flask, url_base_pathname='/pathname')
```

Now you can redirect to your Plotly Dashboard app under any Flask routes you want.

```
@app_flask.route('/plotly_dashboard') 
def render_dashboard():
    return flask.redirect('/pathname')
```

Comment: Let me point out just one thing that I stumbled upon: in your main you should then run the app_flask. I know it may be obvious, but it may save some minutes to beginners like me

Answer (score 20):

Ok for those who are lazy enough like me, here is the code

```
from dash import Dash
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
import flask
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import dash_html_components as html

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
dash_app1 = Dash(__name__, server = server, url_base_pathname='/dashboard' )
dash_app2 = Dash(__name__, server = server, url_base_pathname='/reports')
dash_app1.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for dashboards')])
dash_app2.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app2 for reports')])
@server.route('/')
@server.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello world!'

@server.route('/dashboard')
def render_dashboard():
    return flask.redirect('/dash1')


@server.route('/reports')
def render_reports():
    return flask.redirect('/dash2')

app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
    '/dash1': dash_app1.server,
    '/dash2': dash_app2.server
})

run_simple('0.0.0.0', 8080, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

Comment: I tried your code . it looked like what I was looking for as a test case. I get the following:  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1107, in register_blueprint
    blueprint, self.blueprints[blueprint.name], blueprint.name
AssertionError: A name collision occurred between blueprints <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x1133d8fd0> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x1139184a8>. Both share the same name "assets". Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. I notice that the method worked for one redirection, but not for two redirections to dask apps. I have no clue how the change the assets name.

Comment: It seem that you have to take care of the flask version you use, I had two different experiences when using flask 1.0 and flask 0.12.

Comment: I used dispatch middleware from `werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher` because `werkzeug.wsgi` threw an error.

Here is the [documentation link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appdispatch/) and code:

`from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware`

Comment: Is it possible to pass data posted in a flask route to a dash callback triggering an update in a component (for example a plot)? If you'd like to suggest me to start a new question I already did but it was marked as duplicate.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134233/how-to-share-data-from-a-flask-route-to-a-dash-callback

Comment: Since Dash 2.0 this pattern is not longer supported. Each Dash instance now sets up global state in the dash module, so only one Dash instance should be run in a process at time, otherwise you'll find things breaking in weird and surprising ways

Answer (score 0):

```
#here are full codee
from dash import Dash
import flask
from dash import html

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/ATM_Data_Anlaysis/')
app.layout = html.Div([html.H1('This Is head',style={'textAlign':'center'})])

@server.route("/dash")
def MyDashApp():
    return app.index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -4):

To solve this issue, here is what I did and was successful. This should be documented in official DASH documentation

```
####################################
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, State, Output

from flask          import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template,    request, session, abort, url_for, json, make_response

url_router=''

@application.route("/view_tables", methods=['GET','POST'])
def view_tabales:
  # Logic for displaying dashboard using Dash
  server.layout = html.Div(
                    children=[
                    #division for graph 1
                    html.Div([html.H1(children='Capital Charge'),],className='text-center'),

                    html.Div([html.Div([html.H3(children='''Correlation for assets'''),],className='text-primary'),
                                # define the graph
                                dcc.Graph(
                                    id='Delta-graph',
                                    figure={
                                        'data': [
                                            {'x': df_delta['Correlation_Level'], 
                                             'y': df_delta['Capital_Charge'], 
                                             'type': 'bar', 
                                             'name': 'Delta',
                                             #'domain': {'x': [0, .48],'y': [0, .49]},
                                             }
                                        ],
                                        # sizes the graph
                                        'layout': {
                                            'title': 'Delta','margin': {'l': 10, 'r': 0, 't': 30, 'b': 10},
                                            "height":300,
                                        }
                                    }
                                )],className='col-md-4'),
  url_router = 'Dash(__name__,server=application, url_base_pathname="/dash")'
```

Then you can control which dashboard it is headed from inside flask

```
if url_router !='':
      server = url_router

server.layout = html.Div(children = [html.H1(children = ' MEP dashboard - error 404')])


# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
   # removed before deploying a production app.
   server.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
   server.run_server(debug=True,port=5000)
```

you can create different functions with different graphs between the Flask code and keep calling the code in dash