# Run a dash app inside a flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, plotly-dash

I want to be able to run my dash app from my flask app when I go to a specific url '/dash'. However I get the following error. 'TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.'

flaskapp.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome!'

@app.route('/dash')
def dash_chart():
    dashapp.start() # Run the dash app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

dashapp.py

```
def start():
    app = dash.Dash()
    app.layout = html.Div('Hello World')
    if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If I make the following change to my flaskapp.py,

```
server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/dashapp') #Results in an error

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome!'

@server.route('/dash')
def dash_chart():
    return flask.redirect('/dashapp')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(debug=True)
```

I get the following error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845872/running-a-dash-app-within-a-flask-app)?

Comment: I have but I don't understand the answer. I tried implementing them but I have no idea what I'm doing and my code fails.

Comment: Don't check out the answer at the top, check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47715493/5087436) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849050/5087436). Also check the Dash and Flask section on the [Dash deployment docs](https://dash.plot.ly/deployment).

Comment: I've done exactly that but I'm getting the following error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'

Comment: I think Flask views should always return something other than `None`. In your first solution, try returning a string like `"Dash app is running !"`

Comment: There are some related errors with possible solutions noted on the [Dash GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+NoneType). In particular, check [#220](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/220). It seems that the reason is that Dash is looking for a `Layout`, which is never set in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you never actually built out the Dash application. I get the same errors you get with your code, but actually building out the Dash app (that is, setting the `Layout`) seems to fix the issue. Note that the error traceback specifically shows Dash failing to traverse your layout, because there isn't one. Try creating a `dash.Layout()` for it to parse, so that it has something to serve. An answer to [issue #220](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/220) on Dash's GitHub mentions this same error and solution.

For a MCVE:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import flask

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/dashapp')
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Dash App')])

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return '''
<html>
<div>
    <h1>Flask App</h1>
</div>
</html>
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

Each page should look the same, except that `host:port/` should show the heading "Flask App", while `host:port/dashapp` should show the heading "Dash App".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by setting the Layout or creating a dash.Layout( ). Also from your example, how would I call the dash app(lines 6-8) if it was in another .py like my example? Thanks

Comment: @FsimulatorX a `dash.Layout()` is how you start actually building the dash application. It's just the HTML elements. The Dash application is just a webpage, so it needs HTML elements to render.

Comment: Hi @alkasm, I'm using your method described here, and navigation is working... sort of. When I click my about link, the url is updated in the search bar, but only when I refresh the page do I see my about page. Any idea what is causing this?