# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I'm currently building a Flask Application & I'm trying to load a Plotly Dash App inside of it.

I was able to get this far from the following stackoverflow message board however I don't think I am doing something right (probably overlooking something?)

[Running a Dash app within a Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845872/running-a-dash-app-within-a-flask-app)

Any help here would be immensely appreciated

Here is my server.py code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_moment import Moment 
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_pagedown import PageDown 
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_sslify import SSLify
import os

import dash
import flask

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Here is my views.py:

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash, redirect, 
session, url_for, g, jsonify, make_response
from services.email import send_invite_email, send_recover_email, 
send_password_was_changed_email
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from app import server, app 
from app import db
from models import User, Post 
from forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, ForgotForm, ProfileForm, 
ResetPassword, InviteForm, PostForm
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, 
login_required, LoginManager
import os
from flask_babel import Babel, lazy_gettext
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask_avatar import Avatar
from momentjs import momentjs
from flask_mail import Mail
from dash import Dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, State, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from analysis import * 

df = pd.read_csv(

'/Users.../ds/total/main.csv')



@server.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user


@server.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
    ..... [[more dash code]]

    ])

    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
          [[more dash code]]
    ])
```

Here is my server.py:
        from app import server, app
        server.run(debug=True)

When I run it all, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/..lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1808, in 
full_dispatch_request
 self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
 File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1855, in 
 try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
 func()
 File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 561, in 
_setup_server
self._generate_scripts_html()
File "/Users//lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 245, in 
_generate_scripts_html
self.scripts.get_all_scripts() +
File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/resources.py", line 128, 
in get_all_scripts
return self._resources.get_all_resources()
 File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/resources.py", line 57, 
in get_all_resources
self.get_inferred_resources() + self._resources
File "/Users//lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/resources.py", line 86, 
in 
get_inferred_resources
for t in layout.traverse():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'
```

Comment: @PRMoureu here you go (sorry for not including it in original)

Comment: At first glance, you need some layout defined for dash `app.layout = ...` ([doc](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started#dash-app-layout) ). Also you need to import the `views.py` at some point, after declaring `app` and `server`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when trying to run my Dash app and I fixed it thanks to [this thread](https://community.plot.ly/t/multipage-app-trouble-after-updating-dash-components/6382/2). It is said that you need to change `app:server` to `index:app.server` in the Procfile.

I'm not sure it applies in your case and if you even have a Procfile file but I'm putting this in here for people in the same situation I was.