# When I press backspace after logging out of a flask application, I am still able to access the restricted page using Flask + Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

```
from flask import session
from functools import wraps
import flask
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, session
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user , logout_user , current_user , login_required
from flask_session import Session
import time, dash, os, json, flask, configparser, shutil, base64, io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from dash_table import DataTable
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_daq as daq
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import dash_table.FormatTemplate as FormatTemplate 
from dash_table.Format import Format
from dash_extensions import Download 


def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        user = dict(session).get('profile', None)
        # You would add a check here and usethe user id or something to fetch
        # the other data for that user/check if they exist
        if user:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return render_template('index.html')
    return decorated_function


# AS simeple as possbile flask google oAuth 2.0
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import os
from datetime import timedelta
#dotenv setup
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


# App config
server = Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = 'xxxx'
server.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'google-login-session'
server.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(seconds=120)

# oAuth Setup
oauth = OAuth(server)
google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id='xxxx',
    client_secret='xxxx',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    userinfo_endpoint='https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo',  # This is only needed if using openId to fetch user info
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
)


@server.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    email = dict(session)['profile']['email']
    return render_template('index.html')


@server.route('/login')
def login():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')  # create the google oauth client
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)


@server.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')  # create the google oauth client
    token = google.authorize_access_token()  # Access token from google (needed to get user info)
    resp = google.get('userinfo')  # userinfo contains stuff u specificed in the scrope
    user_info = resp.json()
    user = oauth.google.userinfo()  # uses openid endpoint to fetch user info
    # Here you use the profile/user data that you got and query your database find/register the user
    # and set ur own data in the session not the profile from google
    session['profile'] = user_info
    session.permanent = False  # make the session permanant so it keeps existing after broweser gets closed
    return redirect('/Planner/')


@server.route('/Planner/logout')
def logout():
    for key in list(session.keys()):
        session.pop(key)
    return redirect('/')

app = dash.Dash(__name__, server = server, 
                url_base_pathname='/Planner/')
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = False
app.title = 'Scenario Planner'
app.layout = html.Div([html.Div('Hey'), html.Br(), html.A('Logout', href = './logout')])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(debug=False)
```

This is my code. Basically there is a plotly dash application as well running in my code. Everything works except for restricting access to the dash application. If I use localhost:5000/Planner, irrespective of the authentication, my app is displayed.

If I follow the authentication flow, sign in, and then sign out and then click backspace, the dash application is still accessible. Is there a way I can modify this code to restrict such access.

Answer (score 0):

Using a previous answer which somewhat solved this problem: [Running a Dash app within a Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845872/running-a-dash-app-within-a-flask-app) I have come up with this solution:

You can add this to your code:

```
@server.route('/plotly_dashboard') 
@login_required
def render_dashboard():
    return flask.redirect('/Planner')
```