# How to trigger a serverside callback in dash app from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I have this simple dash app to test how to trigger a serverside callback from within a javascript. However, this does not work! Whenever I click the trigger callback button it DOES change the value of the dcc.input on the browser, but it does NOT trigger the serverside callback.

I have been scratching my head for 3 days so far. So, any help is really appreciated.

I know that I can achieve this by a clientside callback. But my actuall application requries a for-loop inside a callback while displaying the output of each iteration on real-time basis in the browser. So, I can't wait until the clientside callback to end and return the final value. I need to display all the processed outputs during the for-loop as well.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),
    html.Button('Trigger Callback', id='my-button')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('my-output', 'children'),
    Input('my-input', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_output(input_value):
    print(f'Output: {input_value}')
    return f'You\'ve entered: {input_value}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And here is my javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        let myButton = document.getElementById('my-button');
        if (myButton) {
            console.log('myButton:', myButton);
            myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                let inputComponent = document.getElementById('my-input');
                console.log('inputComponent:', inputComponent);
                inputComponent.value = 'New value';
                let event = new Event('input', {bubbles: true});
                inputComponent.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
            clearInterval(checkExist);  // Stop checking once the element is found
        }
    }, 100);  // Check every 100ms
};
```

I tried to dispatch the change to the input component with both 'input' and 'change' but none of them did work.

What I expect is that whenever I click on the "Trigger Callback" button it shall trigger the serverside callback ("update_ouput").

Comment: normally (when you don't use `dash`) it would need to run `flask` or `django` on server and use `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` in `JavaScript`. You could try to use `fetch()` in your code but I don't know if it will work with `@app.callback()` and I don't know if you can use `@app.route(url)` like in `flask`

Comment: it seems you could use `@app.server.route("/your/url")`  in `dash` (similar to `flask`) and later use `fetch("/your/url")` in `JavaScript`. See: [Dash app.routes Flask to Dash - Dash Python - Plotly Community Forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-app-routes-flask-to-dash/51519)

Comment: see more: [python - Running a Dash app within a Flask app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845872/running-a-dash-app-within-a-flask-app)

Answer (score 0):

This is example showing how you can trigger serverside callback from clientside callback:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback, clientside_callback


app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Input('Clientside Input', id='client-input'),

    dcc.Input('Serverside Input', id='server-input'),

    html.H2(id='server-output')

])


clientside_callback(
    """
    function(largeValue1) {
        console.log(largeValue1)
        return largeValue1;
    }
        
    """,
    Output('server-input', 'value'),
    Input('client-input', 'value')
)


@callback(
    Output(component_id='server-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='server-input', component_property='value')
)
def f1(input_):
    print(input_)
    return input_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```